# How to solve " ImportError: No module named mechanize "

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have mechanize module into required folder and still showing problems...
How to solve " ImportError: No module named mechanize "

i saw these:

```
import mechanize
ImportError: No module named mechanize

import mechanize
ImportError: No module named mechanize

noobs = mechanize.Browser()
NameError: global name 'mechanize' is not defined
```

Comment: `pip install mechanize` Write this in you terminal and make sure you have installed pypi

Comment: I did it and still showing same problems....